WordPress menu adding aditional links out of nowhere only on one page - how do I fix?
Whenever I open this page on my website, I get additional invisible links that create empty space on my menu and footer:

I checked the menu to see if there was anything wrong, but this is what it looks like:

The footer looks normal on all the other pages and doesn't have invisible links, it only happens on the Food Insecurity Indices page (and not in its child page):

Any ideas on what the problem is and how to fix it? Thanks!

In Menu settings check the footer checkbox then the save button

What's weird is that you got multiple links within a single li there. If anything (theme/plugin/...) was manipulating the data structure of this menu before it gets rendered, adding new items - then one should reasonably expect that to cause the creation of multiple li. What your screenshot shows, is the DOM inspector view - after the browser has parsed the HTML. Please check what the original HTML source code of that section looks like. If there is any structural errors in that HTML for some reason, it could cause the browser to create two links instead of one.
